# Accessible read only checkbox in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, accessibility

How can I have an **accessible read only checkbox** in Silverlight? The accessibility requirements are so that a screen reader can read the data as the user tabs through the control. Here’s what I have tried so far:

- IsEnabled=True  is no good because the control can not gain focus which is needed for the screen reader
- IsHitTestVisible=False is no good because you can still change the value by pressing the space bar when it has focus
- IsTabStop=False is no good because you can still change the value by clicking the tickbox
- For other controls such as the TextBox, I have used the IsReadOnly property, but this doesn’t seem to be available on the CheckBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you always revert the Checked value when it changes? You could even restyle the control so that the Normal state looked like the not enabled state.